# Scala: Int id in Spring Data Repository

Tags: spring, scala, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create Spring Data Mongo repository using Scala.
My object has Int id, so I my repository looks like

```
trait SamRecordRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository[SamRecord, Int] {
}
```

This code does not compile, because scala Int does not extend Serializable:

```
Error:(10, 29) type arguments [com.cgen.SamRecord2,Int] do not conform to trait PagingAndSortingRepository's type parameter bounds [T,ID <: java.io.Serializable]
trait SamRecordRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository[SamRecord2, Int] {
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use an `Integer` instead? `java.lang.Integer extends Serializable`.